# string formatting python webapp2

Tags: python, html, string, format, webapp2

I am just learning Python Webapp2 from Google sample code guestbook, storing line of text comma separated and display as formatted string. My problem is there are about 11 items in the string separated by comma, but Python '%s' %  or {}. format returns me single line of text. I have tried to convert text to tuple() it gets worse breaking down to list of each characters. What am I missing?

```
    for greeting in greetings:
        if greeting.author:
            self.response.write(
                    '<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
        else:
            self.response.write('Power consumption:')
        self.response.write('<blockquote>%s</blockquote>' %
                            cgi.escape(greeting.content))

        self.response.write(count: '{0}'.format(greeting.content.split(',')))
```

text:

> 85327,'2000/0/0','0:00:00',61.02,76.50,80.16,0.68,0.03,48.91,'2106/2/6','6:28:16'

count: [u'85327', u"'2000/0/0'", u"'0:00:00'", u'61.02', u'76.50', u'80.16', u'0.68', u'0.03', u'48.91', u"'2106/2/6'", u"'6:28:16'"]

---

Guestbook name:
      
      
    
    [Login](/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A11080/)

Comment: What are you trying to write? A number of items in greeting.content ?

Comment: Your question is not clear: what are you trying to achieve? What's the expected output? Where is the declaration of 'greetings'?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get them each on a separate line. Try this:

`self.response.write('\n'.join(greeting.content.split(',')))`

What this does is:

1. Splits the greetings string into an array where each element is a comma separated section
2. Joins each of the array elements together with a `\n` character between each. This is the character for line breaks.

I was't sure what you're doing with the `count:` as that's not valid python.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the quotes, change:
`self.response.write(count: '{0}'.format(greeting.content.split(',')))`

to:

`self.response.write('count: {0}'.format(greeting.content.split(',')))`